# loading div content from external with jQuery.load into own div

Tags: ajax, html, jquery

Let's say that I have two html pages that are identically designed, but have different content. I have the same **div** with the same **id** on both pages. How do I use **jQuery.load** (or what do I use) so that the **div#conent** does not get added into the **div#content** of the first page.

I've tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#linkHome").click(function(){$("div#content").load('index.htm #content');});
  $("a#linkPage2").click(function(){$("div#content").load('page2.htm #content');});
});
```

... but it ends up adding another div to the already existing div!

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="content">
    Blah Blah Blah
  <div id="content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#linkHome").click(function(){$("div#content").load('index.htm #content *');});
  $("a#linkPage2").click(function(){$("div#content").load('page2.htm #content *');});
});
```

in this way you get all elements inside the div#content but not the div itself.

Comment: I was hoping it wasn't something so simple as this, but it worked wonderfully! I'm reminded that jQuery loads body * by default. So this makes lots of sense! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try the opposite approach. Just add a wrapper div into your target page.

Comment: the problem with this approach, I think, is that on a site that rich in content; It can and will get messy.